# How to model a Decision, Choice, and ChoiceSet relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, has-many-through

I've been scratching my head on this data modeling problem for a few days and decided to turn to you fine folks for some assistance.  Although I've been working with Rails for 7+ years, this relationship modeling is escaping me.

I have a `Decision` model, which basically consists of a `:question` attribute, for example:

> Which team will win the Super Bowl this year?

For each `@decision`, there is a corresponding set of `@choices`, for example:

1. Dallas Cowboys
2. New England Patriots
3. New York Giants
4. Green Bay Packers

I'd like to use a model to group this set of `@choices`. Let's call this a `ChoiceSet`.

So to summarize the desired relationship in plain english:

> A Decision has many Choices through a ChoiceSet.

So far, so good.  Here's where I'm getting confused.  Normally one would model this like so:

```
model Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choice_sets
  has_many :choices, through: :choice_sets
end

model Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choice_sets
  has_many :decisions, through: :choice_sets
end

model ChoiceSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
  belongs_to :choice
end
```

**Here's the caveat: The way this is modeled, a decision could have multiple choice sets. How can I model this so that a Decision can only have one choice set?**

Is it as simple as this (simply changing the `has_many :choice_sets` to `has_one :choice_set`?

```
model Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :choice_set
  has_many :choices, through: :choice_set
end

model Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choice_sets
  has_many :decisions, through: :choice_sets
end

model ChoiceSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
  belongs_to :choice
end
```

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

As surfaced by an answer to this question, I should specify that I'd like to avoid saying that a `Choice :belongs_to Decision` so that I don't need to create a new `Choice` record when everything is the same except the `decision_id`.  For example, I don't want to have 2 `Choice` records for "Dallas Cowboys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if we say multiple Decisions can have the same choice set:

> Which team will win the Super Bowl this year?

and

> Which team will come in second in the Super Bowl this year?

We know there's a one to many relationship between ChoiceSet and Decision

Each ChoiceSet can have many Choices, but you're also saying that each Choice can belong to many ChoiceSets... this means you need another join table. The relationship would be something like...

```
model Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :choice_set
  has_many :choices, through: :choice_set
end

model ChoiceSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :decisions
  has_many :choice_set_choice_links
  has_many :choices, through: :choice_set_choice_links
end

model ChoiceSetChoiceLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :choice_set
  belongs_to :choice

model Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many choice_set_choice_links
  has_many choice_sets, through: choice_set_choice_links
  has_many :decisions, through: :choice_sets
end
```

The model Decision has `choice_set_id`
The model ChoiceSetChoiceLink has `choice_set_id` and `choice_id`

Comment: The issue with this — and I should have specified in my original question — is that if a `Choice` has `choice_set_id` then I'll need to generate choice records with duplicate content (potentially) if I have a `ChoiceSet` containing, for example, 'Choice Foo', and then a month later have a new `ChoiceSet` with 'Choice Foo'... I'd like to avoid having duplicate `Choice` records.

Comment: If you're giong to have a many-to-many relationship, you have no choice but a join table.  If a Choice belongs  to many ChoiceSets anda ChoiceSet has many choices, you need a join table between them.  See my edited answer.